# ReactJS: My second React component is not rendering in Page

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I just created an React app using ASP.Net Core framework. I am calling the 2nd component in my Index.cshtml but it's not rendering. However it's throwing an error:
react-dom.development.js:24963 Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

Here is my component code

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="my-class">
                <div>Name: John Doe</div>
                <div>Age: 29</div>
                <div>CIty: Brisbane</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyClass />, document.getElementById("tabled"));
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="content" />

<div id="tabled" />
```

Here is my another component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const products = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product1",
                price: 120
            }, {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product1",
                price: 120
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product1",
                price: 120
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product1",
                price: 120
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: "Product2",
                price: 80
            }];
        return (
            <BootstrapTable data={products} striped hover condensed>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' isKey={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Looking for help, Thanks in advance

Comment: `div` tags are not self closing, should be `<div></div>`

Comment: Thanks so much @AnuragSrivastava :) It worked for me...!

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava can you please also help me in importing and exporting the components using Import in reactjs ... please note that I am using ReactJS as CDN not creating app by NPM or NPX. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would only make one call to ReactDOM.render. I would move the stuff you currently have in App into its own component called Table. Then I would call Table and MyClass from App e.g.

```
class Table extends React.Component {
render() {

    const products = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Product1",
            price: 120
        }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Product1",
            price: 120
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Product1",
            price: 120
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Product1",
            price: 120
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Product2",
            price: 80
        }];
    return (
        <BootstrapTable data={products} striped hover condensed>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' isKey={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
    );
}

class MyClass extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="my-class">
            <div>Name: John Doe</div>
            <div>Age: 29</div>
            <div>CIty: Brisbane</div>
        </div>
    );
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Table/>
        <MyClass/>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Then you can get rid of `<div id="tabled" />` in your html.

Comment: I am sorry, but can You please clear it?
I would move the stuff you currently have in App into its own component called Table.

Comment: You will have 3 components: App, Table and MyClass. You will put Table and MyClass inside App. Then you only have to use ReactDOM.render once.

Comment: What @Paddy is trying to say, you have to separate the code which will be easier to track an issues and avoid rediculous mistakes such as closing div tags. Code will become modular where each component will be as building block.

Comment: Got it...! I've separated all those ;) ...! Thanks Buddies